# how to check if html element is actually at top level and visible

Tags: javascript, html, css

For example I have a dropdown. The last item in the list is my target element. So I can't find a way to know that I can see the element because it can be overlaid by another element. That means I need somehow to know that I can see at least a part of that element on the page. Is it possible to do with js and css.
getComputedStyle().visibility or .display won't be different
when dropdown closed I need to get false, when I open it I want to get true. Even if it's out of screen if I scroll I can see it so it should be true.
I can have a link to that target element, so it should work on every element .

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.dropbtn {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #3e8e41;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>


<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
  <a href="#">Link 1</a>
  <a href="#">Link 2</a>
  <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Depending on your needs, you could always get the bottom of the dropdown via `getBoundingClientRect` and the height of the screen. And see if the bottom is less than or equal to the height than it would be visible.

Comment: I should say that there can be several elements that I want to track (generated and I only have a link to element) so they can be nested

Comment: Generally raising the z-index of the target element (or its container) to make it "on top" would allow scrolling it into view (if you don't do so automatically), so the problem shouldn't apply. However the tactic being pursued in the question leads to another question:  what is the plan if the target element **is** overlaid entirely by something else?

Answer (score 1):

```css
.dropdown-item {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  padding: 12px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 150px;
  text-align: left;
}

/* Style for the dropdown container */
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

/* Style for the dropdown content */
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 150px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
}

/* Style for the dropdown content links */
.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
}

/* Show the dropdown content on hover */
.dropdown:hover > .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropdown-item">Dropdown 1</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">Link 1-1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 1-2</a>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="dropdown-item">Dropdown 1-3</button>
      <div class="dropdown-content sub-dropdown-content">
        <a href="#">Link 1-3-1</a>
        <a href="#">Link 1-3-2</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
/* Show the dropdown content on hover */
.dropdown:hover > .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

in this code in hover > .dropdown-content means first .dropdown-content only show
I hope it's work for you.

Comment: seems the only way is to get the top element by element coordinates and check what it is right now. before/after click